# Github - prevent users to open new repositories without admin permission

Tags: github, github-api

is there a way to limit new repositories creation for all users except for admins in an organization?

I found [this](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-organization-settings/restricting-repository-creation-in-your-organization) article on Github, but this restricts the repository type. I am looking for a way to prevent users to create any new repository, unless an admin in the same organization approved.

Is it even possible with Github?

Answer (score 0):

You were close to the solution. There is actually a link to another section in the documentation you shared named [Enforcing repository management policies in your enterprise account](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-enterprise/setting-policies-for-organizations-in-your-enterprise-account/enforcing-repository-management-policies-in-your-enterprise-account) with a specific section [Enforcing a policy on creating repositories](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-enterprise/setting-policies-for-organizations-in-your-enterprise-account/enforcing-repository-management-policies-in-your-enterprise-account#enforcing-a-policy-on-creating-repositories).

There, you'll see that you can choose whether members can create repositories in your organization.

Here is the step related to it:

[image: Step 5]

Comment: I am admin and owner and there's no "Your enterprises" option in Github menu :(
Does it mean that my company license is not enterprise?

Comment: Does your organization have an [Enterprise account](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-enterprise/managing-your-enterprise-account/about-enterprise-accounts)?